# I created a JS file for this source and called it, and it does not work

Tags: javascript, php

While it works well in PHP,

I have created a JS file and run it and it does not work.

No error message is displayed.

upload.js

```
var dropArea = document.documentElement; // drop area zone JS object
            var progress = document.getElementById('progress'); // text zone where informations about uploaded files are displayed
            var list = []; // file list
            var nbDone = 0; // initialisation of nb files already uploaded during the process.
            var nb=null;
            var nbUploaded = null;
            var oldColor = null;
            var uploadError = false;

            // main initialization
            (function(){

                // init handlers
                function initHandlers() {
                    dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                    dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                }

                // drag over
                function handleDragOver(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    oldColor = dropArea.style.color;
                    dropArea.style.color='red';
                    //dropArea.className = 'hover';
                }

                // drag drop
                function handleDrop(event) {
                    dropArea.style.color=oldColor;
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();

                    processFiles(event.dataTransfer.files);
                }

                // process bunch of files
                function processFiles(filelist) {
                    if (!filelist || !filelist.length || list.length) return;
                    for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length && i < 500; i++) { // limit is 500 files (only for not having an infinite loop)
                        nbUploaded=filelist.length;
                        list.push(filelist[i]);
                    }
                    uploadNext();
                }

                // upload file
                function uploadFile(file, status) {
                    // prepare XMLHttpRequest
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', 'index.php?copy='+document.getElementById('upload-copy').value);
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        uploadNext();
                        nbUploaded--;
                    };
                    var totalTmp = 0;
                    if ( xhr.upload ) {
                        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                            var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                            totalTmp = e.total;
                            var pourcentage = Math.floor(done/total*1000)/10;
                            var progressMessage = "File : " + file['name'] + " ("+file['type']+") progress : " + pourcentage + "%" + " ("+done+"/"+total+" octets)";
                            var fileDiv = document.getElementById('file_'+nbDone+'');
                            fileDiv.textContent = progressMessage;
                        };
                    }
                    
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                            console.log(xhr);
                            var progressMessage = "File : " + file['name'] + " ("+file['type']+") progress : 100%" + " (" + file['size'] + " octets) : ";
                            urlMessage = '<a href="index.php?f='+xhr.responseText+'">'+xhr.responseText+'</a>';
                            var fileDiv = document.getElementById('file_'+nbDone+'');
                            fileDiv.innerHTML =  progressMessage + urlMessage;
                            console.log(nbUploaded);
                            if(nbUploaded==1){
                                dropArea.style.color='#000';
                            }                       
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.onerror = function() {
                        var progressMessage = "File : " + file['name'] + " ("+file['type']+") upload error";
                        var fileDiv = document.getElementById('file_'+nbDone+'');
                        fileDiv.textContent = progressMessage;
                        uploadNext();
                        nbUploaded--;
                        if(nbUploaded==1){
                            dropArea.style.color='#000';
                        }                           
                    };

                    // prepare and send FormData
                    var formData = new FormData();  
                    formData.append('myfile', file);
                    xhr.send(formData);
                }

                // upload next file
                function uploadNext() {
                    if (list.length) {
                        nb = list.length - 1;
                        
                        nbDone +=1;
                        
                        var strTemp = '<div id="file_'+nbDone+'"></div>';
                        progress.innerHTML += strTemp;
                        
                        var nextFile = list.shift();
                        var sizeMax = <?php echo $upload_b;?>;
                        if (nextFile.size >= sizeMax) { // 20Mb = generally the max file size on PHP hosts
                            var progressMessage = "File : " + nextFile['name'] + " ("+nextFile['type']+") File Too big (" + nextFile['size'] + " > "+sizeMax+")";
                            var fileDiv = document.getElementById('file_'+nbDone+'');
                            fileDiv.textContent = progressMessage;
                            uploadError = true;
                            uploadNext();
                            nbUploaded--;
                            if(nbUploaded==1){
                                dropArea.style.color='#000';
                            }                               
                        } else {
                            uploadFile(nextFile, status);
                        }
                    }
                }

                initHandlers();
            })();
```

index.php  (There are not a few of PHP's)

```
<?
$max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
$upload_mb = min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
$upload_b = $upload_mb * 1024 * 1024;
?><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Up</title><meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <section id="midle">
                <div class="upload_form_cont">
                    <?php if(!empty($serverMsg)){?>
                        <div class="error"><?php echo $serverMsg;?></div>
                    <?php }else{?>
                        <div class="info">
                            <div id="upload-zone">Drop your files :-)</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>Number of available copies : <input type="text" id="upload-copy" value="1"></input></div>
                    <?php }?>
                    <div>Max upload size : <?php echo $upload_mb;?> Mb</div>
                    <div id="progress"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="progress"></div>
            <script src="upload.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine in php, but it does not work if you create a separate file called js.

Comment: "It doesn't work" usually doesn't get you far on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some PHP code left in your .js, in uploadNext():

```
var sizeMax = <?php echo $upload_b;?>;
```

Because this is detached from your file this sizeMax variable won't get set.  So you need another way to get sizeMax accessible by javascript.

I suggest you do the following, in index.php, in the `<head>` (by the way you are missing `</head>`:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var maxUpload = <?php echo $upload_b; ?>;</script>
```

Then modify your js code sizeMax line

```
var sizeMax = maxUpload;
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you. How can you find it so quickly? Is there a way? I could not find an error message. And this JS is something strange. Could you fix it more simply?

Comment: There's not really another way that's simpler than this that would work with a detached JS file.  Rather than putting that line in the head you could insert it on the line above `<script src="upload.js"></script>` if that's cleaner for you.

Comment: Thanks you, James

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript around line 111

```
var sizeMax = <? php echo $upload_b; ?> ;
```

Clearly this content was to be modified when served with a configuration value.  Try setting it to 1gb:

```
var sizeMax = 1073741824;
```

Comment: It works well. Thank you.


How can you find it so quickly? Is there a way? I could not find an error message.

Comment: I copied the code and dropped it onto a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), it's a handy web tool.